# Measure total latency of SSH session

Tags: networking, ssh, performance-monitoring, latency

Is there a way to measure/report the *overall* latency in a tunneled SSH session?

My particular setup is:

- Client (OS X + wifi router + ADSL modem)
- Gateway SSH server exposed to Internet
- Internal SSH target to which I'm tunneling

I'm interested in seeing the latency between the console on my local machine and the final machine on which I have the session open.

Comment: Why not SSH tunnel to the first server, and then SSH console to the second server.

Answer (score 21):

See the `sshping` utility:  https://github.com/spook/sshping

Example:

```
# sshping 172.16.47.143
--- Login: 1725 msec
--- Minimum Latency: 4046 nsec
---  Median Latency: 11026 nsec  +/- 0 std dev
--- Average Latency: 178105 nsec
--- Maximum Latency: 8584886 nsec
---      Echo count: 1000 Bytes
---  Transfer Speed: 11694919 Bytes/second

# sshping --help
Usage: sshping [options] [user@]addr[:port]

  SSH-based ping that measures interactive character echo latency
  and file transfer throughput.  Pronounced "shipping".

Options:
  -c  --count NCHARS   Number of characters to echo, default 1000
  -e  --echocmd CMD    Use CMD for echo command; default: cat > /dev/null
  -h  --help           Print usage and exit
  -i  --identity FILE  Identity file, ie ssh private keyfile
  -p  --password PWD   Use password PWD (can be seen, use with care)
  -r  --runtime SECS   Run for SECS seconds, instead of count limit
  -t  --tests e|s      Run tests e=echo s=speed; default es=both
  -v  --verbose        Show more output, use twice for more: -vv
```

Comment: Not to confuse with `ssh-ping` from [ssh-tools](https://github.com/vaporup/ssh-tools).

Comment: FYI I was able to get this to build on macOS with: `brew install libssh`, `cd sshping-master/src`, `g++ -I ~/.homebrew/Cellar/libssh/0.10.4/include -I ../ext -L ~/.homebrew/Cellar/libssh/0.10.4/lib -lssh sshping.cxx`

Comment: I was able to compile this on an Apple Silicon MPB with `brew install. libssh` and `g++ -Wall -I /opt/homebrew/include -I ext -L /opt/homebrew/lib -o bin/sshping src/sshping.cxx -lssh`

Answer (score 10):

I skipped some steps suggested by @nicht-verstehen:

```
python -m timeit --setup 'import subprocess; p = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "user@host", "cat"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)' 'p.stdin.write(b"z"); assert p.stdout.read(1) == b"z"'
```

Where

`python -m timeit` executes the `timeit` Python module.

The `-s/--setup` option tells `timeit` which statement(s) to execute before each repeat.

`subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "user@host", "cat"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)` launches `ssh` - executing `cat` on your host - as a child/subprocess, redirecting its IO streams to Python file-like objects. `bufsize=0` makes sure no IO is buffered, which may cause IO waits.

And for each loop:
`p.stdin.write(b"z")` writes a single byte to the child (in turn through ssh to `cat`).
`p.stdout.read(1)` reads a single byte from the child. The assertion around it tests whether that byte is the same as the one you wrote to it.

Boils down to the same thing, but skips creating the named pipes (`mkfifo`). I noticed that the more loops you run, the faster each loop is. Control it using `-n/--number`: `python -m timeit --number 50 ...`

Comment: If you swap the string delimiters (i.e., `'` and `"`) then you can replace `user@host` with a bash variable.

Comment: Good point @Leo! thanks.

Comment: This is a great snippet, but there is one issue. You noticed that the more loops you run, the faster each loop is. That's because when you send the first "z", the connection is not initialized yet. You can add `; p.stdin.write(b"z"); assert p.stdout.read(1) == b"z"` to the end of the `--setup` to wait for the initialization, and then the resulting time will be correct. It won't be faster when you increase the loops.

Comment: The modified command: `python -m timeit --setup 'import subprocess; p = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "user@host", "cat"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0); p.stdin.write(b"z"); assert p.stdout.read(1) == b"z"' 'p.stdin.write(b"z"); assert p.stdout.read(1) == b"z"'`

Answer (score 8):

Was trying to do this myself and came up with this. Probably there is a simpler way, but this is what I came up with.

First, prepare pipes which will be used to make the benchmarking program communicate through the SSH connection.

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/up /tmp/down
```

Then establish a connection in ControlMaster mode without executing any remote command. This allows us to authenticate with the host interactively. After the connection is established, SSH will just "hang" here in foreground.

```
$ ssh $HOST -N -M -S /tmp/control
```

In a parallel terminal, execute remote `cat` in background. It will be our echo server whose latency we will measure. Inputs and outputs are connected to FIFOs:

```
$ ssh $HOST -S /tmp/control cat </tmp/up >/tmp/down &
```

And then benchmark a small program (send a byte to `up` FIFO, receive a byte from `down` FIFO):

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import os' \
    'os.write(3, "z"); z=os.read(4, 1); assert z=="z", "got %s" % z' \
    3>/tmp/up 4</tmp/down
10 loops, best of 3: 24.6 msec per loop
```

The measure obviously shows the round-trip latency. If you need to repeat the experiment, run the last two commands (`ssh` and `python`) again.

If something seems to go wrong, use SSH `-v` flag to get more debugging output.

Answer (score 6):

My idea was to use terminal query sequences for this; the advantage is that this can simply be run on the server, the disadvantage is that it measures terminal latency, not only the latency of the connection (but i guess, usually, your terminal's response time will be negligible compared to network delays)—maybe this is even what you mean with *overall* latency

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Measure terminal latency (round-trip time) using "Query device code" command
from sys import stdin, stdout
import tty, termios, time

oldtty = termios.tcgetattr(stdin)
try:
    tty.setcbreak(stdout)

    runs = 10
    results = []
    for _ in range(runs):
        stdout.write("\x1b[c")
        stdout.flush()
        t1 = time.time()
        ch = stdin.read(1)
        assert(ch == '\x1b')
        t2 = time.time()
        while stdin.read(1) != 'c': # swallow rest of report
            continue
        latency = (t2 - t1) * 1000
        print('%.1fms' % (latency))
        results.append(latency)

    print()
    print('avg: %.1fms min: %.1fms max: %.1fms' % (
        sum(results) / runs,
        min(results),
        max(results)))
finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, oldtty)
```

(This uses "Device Code Query", all terminals that I've tried respond to this: xterm, alacritty, gnome-terminal. I cannot myself try this on MacOS. So YMMV, if this one doesn't, another of the requests that interrogate some information about the terminal might work, see http://web.archive.org/web/20190624214929/http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)

Comment: This answer could still use some explanation for those not as familiar with tty internals (e.g., why `\x1b[c` would be favorable)

Comment: not sure it's favorable, i think it's a valid discussion: any from the "Device Status" http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm would work, given the terminal supports it, and i have no idea what's well-supported, but my guess is that the basic status query would be (even works in bare-bones Alacritty)

Comment: i think `\x1b[c` is `Query Device Code: <ESC>[c`

Comment: I loved this solution because it doesn't require any setup or installation, just a working python3 environment on the destination. Very helpful if you have multiple SSH layers or other weird configurations.

Comment: Wow, I just found out that my VTE based terminals show a 10ms lag whereas my xterm only 0.1. BTW, the link to `vtansi.htm` is dead but there is a [copy on archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20190624214929/http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

Answer (score 2):

[`ssh_ping`](https://github.com/jacobsa/ssh_ping) is a small Go program for this that is easier to build than the C++ one in another answer if you already have Go installed (and if you don't it's as easy as `brew install go` on macOS):

```shell
> go install github.com/jacobsa/ssh_ping
> ssh_ping --host some.host.com
100 samples so far...
200 samples so far...
Collected 294 samples.

Min:      13.0 ms
p05:      13.6 ms
p50:      13.0 ms
p95:      21.1 ms
Max:      26.0 ms

Mean:     17.0 ms
Std. dev:  2.6 ms
```

Comment: Does this work through a jump host as specified in the question? It seems like it does if because if I use a target specified in my ssh_config with a JumpHost but not sure how to confirm

Comment: It should; it just runs the `ssh` binary, so it’s realistic in doing whatever that does. Certainly it works for the proxy case in my question (although it’s not a `JumpHost` in particular).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Bash script that repeatedly calculates ping-pong RTT/latency. The basic concepts are similar to what others have suggested. The main part does something along these lines:

```bash
fifo="fifo"; mkfifo "$fifo"; sleep=1; now=(date +%s%N)

( echo 'o' >"$fifo"; ) & # to trigger the following loop

cat 0<> "$fifo" | ssh $sshargs $ssh cat \
| while read -r R ; do
   echo $(( $(date +%s%N)-now ))
   sleep "$sleep"
   echo 'o' >"$fifo"
   now=$(date +%s%N)
done
```

I have to admit it works better than I expected :]

Example output for my [`sshpingpong`](https://gist.github.com/xrat/a3df5ff7c63f5c648708825f45372ea9):

```
Logfile is spp_example_net.log
2022-07-24 14:41:00  seq=0  13.349
2022-07-24 14:41:05  seq=1  14.640
2022-07-24 14:41:10  seq=2  13.990
2022-07-24 14:41:15  seq=3  12.802
2022-07-24 14:41:20  seq=4  12.070
2022-07-24 14:41:25  seq=5  11.869
...
```

Example output of compact mode using `sshpingpong -L -c user@example.net` where "_" means the RTT was <100ms and e.g.  "2" means the RTT was >=200 and < 300ms:

```
0 _ 100 1 200 2 300 3 400 4 500 5 600 6 700 7 800 8 900 9 999 # ...
__________________________1_________________________1__________
______________________________________1____________#_2_________
____1____________________________________#______1______________
____1_____________________________________________1_____1___1__
_____________________1____1____________________________________
__________1__________________1__________________1______________
___2___________________1_______________________________________
_____________________22____1____11____59####4444454523444543444
12222#21112______#________________...
```

The full script is available as [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/xrat/a3df5ff7c63f5c648708825f45372ea9).